# Is it possible to programatically initiate a C-Spy system macro (e.g. __memorySave()) in IAR workbench v6.4?

Tags: arm, iar

Is it possible to write a function in the application code that executes one of the IAR C-Spy system macros, independent of the breakpoints in debug mode?

Comment: What architecture are you using? Offhand, I'd say that there's no easy way, but depending on the architecture and why you are looking to avoid breakpoints, you might be able to make something work.

Comment: The reason I ask is because if you're using EWARM, you may be able to manually insert a breakpoint in your code using the assembly `bkpt #0` (there is an intrinsic, too, probably `__bkpt()`). This doesn't count against your breakpoint limit (if that's why you're avoiding breakpoints), and you might be able to get C-SPY to run a macro on a breakpoint inserted like this.

Comment: Yes using EWARM. 
The reason I wanted to avoid the breakpoints is that while the code is halted, the UART line is blocked and can't be used to drump memory.
At the end of the day, I just wanted a convenient way to get a dump of a certain segment of memory in real time when a certain part of code is executed, without me manually having to manually break, collect, continue... etc.

Comment: Depending on the part you may have the.... uh... micro trace buffer (I think that's what it's called) where you could dump your memory to from within the program. I haven't used it, but it's supposed to be a way to implement in-app trace, if I recall correctly. I'd look into that or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldn't get a way to make it work. 
I just ended up writing to a file and passing that through UART without initiating a breakpoint.